# Add Multiple Secured Domains to Different apps on Amazon Lightsail Windows Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, iis-10, amazon-lightsail

I have a domain in Godaddy and an Amazon Lightsail Windows Server 2019. I am trying to point the main domain and subdomain to two different IIS sites. For example.

- **example.com** to **IIS App1**
- **app.example.com** to **IIS App2**

Well, this scenario is simple enough if I point my domain and subdomain to a static IP by adding an A record. I was able to point.

- **http://example.com** to **IIS App1**
- **http://app.example.com** to **IIS App2**

but this way my connection was not secure and I wanted to add an SSL certificate.

To add the SSL in Lightsail I have done the following.

1. Created DNS Zones in Lightsail and point my Godaddy domain to it
2. Create a static IP in Lightsail
3. Created Cloudfront Distribution in Lightsail
4. Created SSL Certificate and enabled Custom Domain

Now SSL is successfully installed and I am able to access my main domain but both of the domains point to **IIS APP1**

- **https://example.com** to **IIS App1**
- **https://app.example.com** to **IIS App1**

How can I point **https://app.example.com** to **IIS App2** using Amazon Lightsail Cloudfron Distribution?

Please note that in IIS APP2 I have added binding for **app.example.com** for port 80 and 443 and Require Server Name Indication is Checked.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps:
you need to setup up 'virtual hosts' within the Lightsail instance,
and then configure/replace the single HTTPS cert to support both domains.

This is a Ubuntu/Apache based guide, but similar should be possible via IIS:

https://tutorialsjoint.com/multiple-domain-configuration-lightsail/